# $s^T A s\geq 0 $ where $A_{ij}=K_{it} K_{jt}-\alpha \sum_{r\ne t} K_{ir} K_{jr}$, what about $s$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

I have a kernel matrix, i.e. $K_{ij}=k(x_i,x_j)$ where $k(x_i,x_j)$ is a positive definite reproducing kernel. Consider this matrix, made from elements of $K$, $A_{ij}=K_{it} K_{jt}-\alpha \sum_{r\ne t} K_{ir} K_{jr}$.

My question is if we have the constraint: $s^T A s = \sum_{i,j} s_i s_j A_{ij} \geq 0$, what is a simpler condition about $s$? If $A$ was positive semidefinte, then the above answer $s\epsilon R^n$. Now $A$ is not semidefinte but is related to semidefinte matrix in the above form, is there any simpler constarint similar to the above constraint about $s$?

Comment: Could you restate the final line of your question?  I don't quite understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to know is if we have that constraint, can we restate it in terms of K matrix or kernel function simpler.